# Can we set ignore_malformed flag true of an already existing index in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch. I'm re-indexing old index to new index. but while re-indexing millions of records sometime, I am getting mapper_parsing_exception exception. so my question is that, Is there a way to set ignore_malformed flag true of an already existing index.

Comment: When reindexing, you should always explicitly set the mapping of the target index before launching the reindex, because the reindex doesn't do it for you.

Comment: yeah, I understand that.. but our old index has dynamic mapping and our new index has static mapping. but I think in dynamic mapping by default ignore_malformed flag is true. so now when re-indexing we are getting mapping_parser_exception. is there way to avoid it.

Comment: You can set `ignore_malformed` [at the index level](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed-setting) before kicking off the reindexing

Comment: but it is possible to set ignore_malformed flag true of already exist index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to change the [`ignore_malformed` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) dynamically simply by running this:

```
PUT logstash_june_2019/doc/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "createdAt": {
      "type" : "date",
      "ignore_malformed": true             <--- add this
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution... but elasticsearch throwing exception: resource_already_exists_exception

Comment: Can you show what you executed exactly? And which version of ES are you using?

Comment: ES verison: 6.4.2
PUT logstash_june_2019/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "createdA": {
      "type" : "long",
      "ignore_malformed": true  
    }
  }
}

Comment: What do you get when running `GET logstash_june_2019`?

Comment: all the mapped field of index logstash_june_2019

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see the response you get, please

Comment: actully response is very big:
 "logstash_june_2019": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "_all": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "appt_date_time": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "appt_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "createdAt": {
            "type": "date"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225355/discussion-between-naresh-singh-and-val).